# Best way to get the current month number in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I am using C# to get current month number:

```
string k=DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
```

For January it will return `1`, but I need to get `01`. If December is the current month, I need to get `12`. Which is the best way to get this in C#?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
string sMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
```

Comment: What if we need to get the MM for any other month?

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran someDate.ToString("MM yyyy")

Answer (score 11):

Lots of different ways of doing this.

For keeping the semantics, I would use the `Month` property of the `DateTime` and format using one of the [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx):

```
DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 9):

```
    using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Get the current month integer.
    //
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    //
    // Write the month integer and then the three-letter month.
    //
    Console.WriteLine(now.Month);
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("MMM"));
    }
}
```

> Output

5

May

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("0#")
```